# Word order in a sentence using 'that'

Tags: word-order, that

Can I change the word order whatever way I want? They all appear to make sense but are they grammatically correct?

1. It was so hot yesterday that I went swimming.
2. Yesterday, it was so hot that I went swimming.
3. It was so hot that I went swimming yesterday.

Comment: You can often move words or phrases to different places in a sentence to give them extra emphasis. In the second sentence _yesterday_ is the focus (or _topic_ or _theme_ - terms from _information packaging_), whereas in the other two the focus is the temperature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes all your sentences have the same meaning and are all grammatically correct:

> so hot -> went swimming -> both events yesterday

Comment: The  question is not really of ELU standard, and an answer lacking supporting evidence certainly isn't.